# Can not scan a directory in another server

Tags: php, unc, scandir

I have stuck with this problem from the morning, I want to scan a directory on another server
`\\\\TARIK3\Paretanires\SGM\recv` but I have this problem :

> Warning: scandir(\TARIK3\Partenaires\SGM\recv,\TARIK3\Partenaires\SGM\recv): in C:\wamp\www\TRAITMENT DONEES\index.php on line 7

The code is :

```
$dir = "\\\\TARIK3\Partenaires\SGM\\recv";
$folder = scandir($dir);    
$Fichier = fopen($folder[2], 'r');
```

Comment: what is the warning about? You left out the warning message

Comment: possible duplicate of [Php read file contents of network share file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070545/php-read-file-contents-of-network-share-file)

Comment: I'm using Windows server 2008

Comment: @ADILELALAOUI - have a look at the answers to the suggested duplicate - one of those gives a solution for Windows (in short - you need to escape the `\` between folder names)

Comment: As suggested by @andrewsi . Try this: `$dir = "\\\\TARIK3\\Partenaires\\SGM\\recv";`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento I have already tested, Nothing!!!

Comment: The problem is in `fopen` you forgot to put the absolute path. Read my answer.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento it still fails because the problem comes from scandir() first, it can not scan the folder because it's in another server, i don't know if the issue is due to permissions, because i grant access from this station to other via explorer.exe and it's mapped

Comment: @ADILELALAOUI Improved and fixed code, try again.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento I've got as a result : Not found: "\\TARIK3\Partenaires\SGM\recv\"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What causes the problem in windows:

Apparently the problem is that apache uses an anonymous/local account and needs a "network/domain account"

### How to Solve:

1. Open "Start Menu" -> Run (or WindowKey+R) and typing `Services.msc` and pressing
   enter.
2. Find the Apache service. Having never used WAMP, I have no idea what it's been named. Hopefully it starts with the word "Apache" (or wampapache) though, and thus shouldn't be too hard to find.
3. Right-click on the service and select Properties.
4. Switch to the Log On tab.
5. Select the radio button next to "This account:" and enter in the credentials for the user account you want to run Apache under. **If it's a network/domain account**, use the `DOMAIN\user` syntax (or search for the account using the Browse button)
6. Select OK and restart the Apache service.
7. Verify that your changes worked by looking for the "httpd.exe" process in Task Manager and checking to see which user name the process is running under.

And try:

`$dir = '\\\\TARIK3\\Partenaires\\SGM\\recv\\';`

or mapped:

`$dir = 'Z:\\Partenaires\\SGM\\recv';`

or:

`$dir = 'Z:\\recv';` (Depends on how you mapped drives)

### To add a service account to the local administrators group

1. In Administrative Tools, click Computer Management.
2. In the console tree, expand Local Users and Groups, and then click Groups.
3. Right-click the Administrators group, and then click Add to Group.
4. Click Add.
5. Click Look in to display a list of domains from which users and groups can be added to the group.
6. In Location, click the domain containing the users and computers you want to add, and then click OK.
7. In Enter the object names to select, type the name of the user or group you want to add to the group, and then click OK.
8. If you want to validate the user or group names that you are adding, click Check Names.

### sources:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737693%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php#79685

http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10371870-RESOLVED-Connection-to-a-network-Drive-Using-PHP/page2

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11186808/1518921

Comment: I tried your code but I have this warning
`Warning: scandir(\\TARIK3\Partenaires\SGM\recv\): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\TRAITMENT DONEES\test.php on line 3`

Comment: I've got as a result : Not found: "\\TARIK3\Partenaires\SGM\recv\"

Comment: @ADILELALAOUI It is clear that the file or folder does not exist, make sure it exists first.

Comment: yes this is the problem, but when i browse to it i find it easily, why WAMP can not access to it?

Comment: Both machines are windows? Check the folder permissions?

Comment: yes both machines are windows, the first is Windows Server 2008 and the second is Windows 8, Folder permissions are full rights !!!

Comment: I copied your "php.ini" I am analyzing

Comment: @ADILELALAOUI forgive me for the delay, please see I edited my question

Comment: I tried to copy it with another software : PlanetPress WorkFlow, but the same problem, I think that you have right because programme needs rights to access to mapped files even if we can access to them manually, because manually means we use explorer.exe that have already all rights. 
I will try it tomorrow and respond you because i'm not anymore on the office, thank you very much again.

Comment: I tested you solution, unfortunately i see just the hosted groups and not groups in the other station,  I think that there is a trouble in network between both stations, that's why when i try with another software it won't works, BUT I CAN SAY THAT YOUR SOLUTION WAS PERFECT AND CORRECT.

Comment: Excuse me for delay, we finally find the problem, the problem was permissions on folders in station TARIK3, they were not allowed to all right except reading, that's why the other software fails also, thank you again for you special help.

Comment: Welcome, glad I could help with something. I wish you luck and success!