# Check if network drive is mapped php

Tags: php, unc, mapped-drive

Does php allow you to check if a network drive is mapped. Essentially on all computers our G:\ drive is mapped. Is it possible using php script to check if the G:\ drive is mapped? In order to access directories and files from the mapped drive I use UNC names.

Help much appreciated

Comment: Try checking this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592910/mapped-network-drives

Comment: You need to run PHP on all the specific computers though.

Comment: Hope you have not any plan to create a application and use it on client browser and check that network drive is there configured on client PC or not. Then surely you will not be able to do that for security reason.

Comment: Perhaps something I forgot to include. php is running under xampp on the server. Xampp is also running as a service. So mapped drives are not accessible using php functions while xampp is running as a service. I have tried all of the above but to no avail. Is there any other way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Why should you use php to access to a client path? 
file_exists should work as well but i don't understand the point :)

```
<?php
$mydir = "G:\ ";

echo file_exists($mydir) ? "G is mounted":"G is not mounted";
?>
```

Comment: Does not actually work unfortunately, but if you add a folder name after the drive letter it does like `$mydir = "G:\data$ ";`

Comment: Perhaps something I forgot to include. php is running under xampp on the server. Xampp is also running as a service. So mapped drives are not accessible using php functions while xampp is running as a service. I have tried all of the above but to no avail. Is there any other way around this?

Comment: David have you considered to use Javascript? :D

Comment: seriously the only way is install a service client side that answer for example via ssh or on a specific port, do the check and send the result to a php page or another service on the server